# How can I extract the integers from this url for nginx rewrite?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a url that I need nginx to interpret and rewrite.

I'm ok with nginx configurations but I'm not very good at all at using regex.

A typical URL will be like this:

```
/open/M-100_L-200_N-300_I-400.jpg
```

and it needs to be rewritten to be like this:

```
/open.php?M=100&L=200&N=300&I=400
```

I suspect it will be something like...

```
location /open/ {
rewrite ^/open/M-([0-9]+)_L-([0-9]+)_N-([0-9]+)_I-([0-9]+) /open.php?M=$1&L=$2&N=$3&I=$4
}
```

Note the values will always be integers of varying length/size.

This just matches the entire filename rather than the individual values within it.

Again, my problem is I'm terrible at using regex and should really put some time aside to understand it.

Comment: It works in JS: https://regex101.com/r/txGIb2/1. I've never Regexed in Nginx, maybe you need a backslash to escape the forward slashes?

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the `rewrite` statement, but otherwise, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to put directly in `server` context and use `\d` for digits:

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite "^/open/M-(\d+)_L-(\d+)_N-(\d)+_I-(\d)+.jpg$" /open.php?M=$1&L=$2&N=$3&I=$4 last;
    ...
}
```

- `\d` = single digit
- `+` = more than one, so `\d+` is for variable length integer
- `()` is for capture, so that the match is available as e.g. `$1` in the rewrite